# Chrome Javascript Error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Have a look at this [link](http://unwrapindia.com/stores/unwrapindia/products/1/Artisan/2/Happily-Unmarried/44/Chandigarh/185/House-Warming/65/New-Year).

The menu to the left is not clickable in chrome (When you open in new tab, it works fine), but works fine in Mozilla.

Please let me know if you have any thoughts on how to correct this.

Comment: How are you handling the `click` events? Prototype, jQuery, `onclick`... so many to choose from!

Comment: Also, on first inspection there are duplicate id attributes - `<label id="Label1">` that will be causing an issue for JavaScript in determining which element to return. `id` should be unique on a page.

Comment: Please, also see a doctor about the other [120+ validation problems](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Funwrapindia.com%2Fstores%2Funwrapindia%2Fproducts%2F1%2FArtisan%2F2%2FHappily-Unmarried%2F44%2FChandigarh%2F185%2FHouse-Warming%2F65%2FNew-Year&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)!

Answer (score 0):

**My solution is add inline javascript code to tag A**

```
onclick="document.location.href=this.getAttribute('href');"
```

**Note**

In html specification, an A element is not allowed to contain a DIV element, you can refer to 
http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html
for more information

Answer (score 0):

Your menu not using Javascript to detect click events it is anchor tag. You will notice that in a **webkit browser** hovering over the link does not provide a pointer cursor.

Eg:

```
<a style="background-color:red;" href="/stores/unwrapindia/products/1/Artisan/2/Happily-Unmarried/65/New-Year/78/Promotions-">
    <div class="fillDIV">
       <input type="checkbox" name="attribute_value_44" value="44" class="CheckBoxClass" id="CheckBox1">
       <label class="LabelSelected" for="CheckBox1" id="Label1">Chandigarh</label>
    </div>
</a>
```

The problem could that the input is conflicting with the anchor tag in regards to the click event, because **webkit** is a bit confused about the div inside the anchor or you need to clean up your ID's. I do not see the reason for your using of the input and label, so at least test it with just the anchor.

Answer (score 0):

The label elements within your links have a `for` attribute (which refer to hidden checkboxes). Something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" />
<a href="http://google.com"><label for="cb1">mooooo</label></a>
```

The link does not work once you set that attribute.
To fix your problem, simply remove the attribute - it does not benefit you anyway (having the checkbox checked is not helpful as you are navigating away from the page).

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/JZ7SG/1/).